# Why object becomes messy when subdivision surface modifier is added

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface

I have this object:

[image]

This is how vertices look like:

[image]

When I add subdivision surface modifier it becomes like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you applied the scale and checked for inverted normals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have this kind of shape, here is what it gives when you give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, it will add topology in the middle of the hole:

[image]

So you have two choices, either add topology to avoid the problem:

[image]

Or don't use *Subdivision Surface* but right click > *Shade Smooth* your object and use the *Auto Smooth* option:

[image]